# pass Mat to CvMat* segmentation fault

Tags: opencv, segmentation-fault, mat

I want to pass a value to a pointer variable, namely from type Mat to CvMat*?

So I have something like the following and want to pass it to the variable Si;;

```
Mat S=(Mat_<double>(1, 3) << 1,0,1 );
CvMat* Si;
*Si=S;
```

But this gives a segmentation fault, Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use

`Si = &S` if you wanted to change the pointer.

Or initialize Si first to copy S into Si

```
Si = new Mat_<double>(1, 3);
*Si = S;
```

Basically before you initialize Si, it is an invalid pointer, and assuming you want to copy a structure to whatever address the pointer refers to, is an invalid operation. You need to "own" a valid memory address (which the `new` operation creates for you) in order to work on an object.

Don't forget to use `delete Si;` at some point later on.

Comment: Your example doesn't compile.

Comment: I initialized Si with cvCreateMat(1,3,CV_32F) and now it worked, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate storage for the object referenced by the pointer. This can be done by calling `cvCreateMat()`, as below:

```
cv::Mat S=(cv::Mat_<double>(1, 3) << 1,0,1 );
CvMat* Si = cvCreateMat(1, 3, CV_64FC1);
*Si=S;
```

Note that this approach will copy the data from `S` into `Si`. If you want to only create a `CvMat` header without copying the data, do this:

```
cv::Mat S=(cv::Mat_<double>(1, 3) << 1,0,1 );
CvMat m = S;
CvMat* Si = &m;
```